# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'generateCards'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to, inside my object Board, call a function in my Board's prototype. Looking at other stack overflow posts, I don't see anything immediately wrong with this. However, I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'generateCards". I'm not sure why this is.

```
function Board(startingPlayer, players){
    this.cards = this.generateCards(10);
}

Board.prototype.generateCards = function(numCardsToGenerate){
        return "I have accessed this function";
}
```

Comment: how is the new board created

Comment: Forgot the `new` keyword when instantiating?

Comment: Make sure you're using `new` when creating a new board.

Comment: @VLS Didn't you see that I wrote the same thing 1 second before? :p

Comment: looks like you are using `Boar()` instead of `new Board()` see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kPqpF/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new board object using the `new` keyword else `this` inside the `Board` function will refer to the `window`(undefined in strict mode) object which does not have the `generateCards` method.

So try

```
var b1 = new Board();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kPqpF/), [Strict Mode](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kPqpF/4/)

In the fiddle the second board creation is throwing the error

Comment: Ah, opps. Thanks! I completely did not realize that. All that debugging for such a silly mistake.